# I removed infinite values from my dataset but it didnt work?

Tags: pandas

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6rZG.jpg

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but how can my dataframe still have infinite values if I removed them? What is the proper way to get rid of infinite values?

edit:
`print(main_df.info())` prints this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhO1R.jpg

Comment: check type of your data. I think you are using str

Comment: This is what my data looks like: https://imgur.com/a/Re9UA8U

Comment: that does not clear my doubt

Answer (score 2):

You used `.dropna()` and this won't work with infinite values immediatly.
I would use `replace` followed by `.dropna()`. The problem with your code is you should redefine your `main_df` regardless of passing the argument `inplace=True`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
main_df = main_df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
main_df = main_df.dropna(how="any")
```

Or in 1 line:

```
main_df = main_df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).dropna(how="any")
```

Comment: I get it, but even after I did that, it still return True when I check that is there still infinite values in the dataframe

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output of `print(main_df.info())` please?